# Abelian subgroup of the unit quaternions

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups, quaternions, unitary-matrices

Let $\Bbb S^0(\Bbb H)\cong \mathrm{SU}(2)$ denote the multiplicateive group of unit *quaternions*.
This group is non-abelian.

Of course, the subgroups generated by as $\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}\<1,i\>$, $\<1,j\>$ and $\<1,k\>$ are commutative and also isomorphic to $\Bbb S^0(\Bbb C)\cong\mathrm U(1)$ (the multiplicative group of unit complex numbers).
And there are probably other such subgroups conjugate to the ones named above.
And of course, any subgroup of such a conjugate is also abelian.

> **Question:** Are there other abelian subgroups of $\Bbb S^0(\Bbb H)$?

Comment: Any cyclic subgroup is obviously abelian.

Comment: @freakish I suppose that any cyclic subgroup is a subgroup of a conjugate of $\langle 1,i\rangle$. Or not?

Comment: That would imply that entire $\mathbb{S}^0(\mathbb{H})$ is a union of conjugates of $\langle 1,i\rangle$. Hmm, I'm not sure, although I do doubt it.

Comment: @freakish I would not be surprised. This sounds like the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) that covers $\Bbb S^3$ by disjoint $\Bbb S^1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slup's answer tells us that all abelian subgroups are contained in maximal abelian subgroups which in turn are products of $n$ circles. The number $n$ is the rank of the group, hence also the number of nodes in the dynkin diagram which is $1$ for $SU(2)$ (or more generally $n = N-1$ for $SU(N)$). It remains to see **why** we have $n= 1$ in this case. I will type a very 'quaternionic' (as opposed to $SU(N)$-ic) answer to this. (The answer will also point out in which circle group the given abelian group lies and why.)

Let $u$ be a unit quaternion that is completely imaginary, i.e. $u \in \mathbb{R}i \oplus \mathbb{R}j \oplus \mathbb{R}k$. The subspace $\mathbb{C}_u := \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}u$ is a subalgebra of $\mathbb{H}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ via the isomorphism $u \mapsto i$. We even have that there is an exponential map $\exp: \mathbb{R}u \to \mathbb{C}_u$ that maps the imaginary axis in $\mathbb{C}_u$ to the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}_u$ in the standard way: $\exp$ is defined by the same Taylor series as it always is and convergence works just as always since $\mathbb{H}$ is, from a topological perspective, just $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Now this unit circle in $\mathbb{C}_u$, which I will denote $S^1_u$ is one of the maximal abelian subgroups that we were talking about. Concretely I claim:

**Claim:** let $A$ be any abelian subgroup of $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{H})$ containing an element $\alpha 1 + \beta u$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ then $A \subset S^1_u$.

The proof is very simple: pick arbitrary $x$ **not** in $S^1_u$ and show that it does not commute with $\alpha 1 + \beta u$.

To simplify this: since we are dealing with unit quaternions $x \not\in S^1_u$ is the same as saying $x \not\in \mathbb{C}_u$. We know that $x$ is of the form $\gamma 1 + \delta u + \epsilon v$ with $\gamma, \delta, \epsilon$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $v$ a unit quaternion that is both purely imaginary AND not in $S^1_u$. To show that $\alpha 1 + \beta u$ does not commute with $x$ it suffices to show that $u$ does not commute with $v$ since everyting inside $\mathbb{C}_u$ *does* commute with eachother.

Now we just need to remember that for purely imaginary quaternions $u$ and $v$ we have that $\Re(uv) = \Re(vu), \Im(uv) = - \Im(vu)$ and that $\Im(uv) = 0$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are real scalar multiples of each other. (Here I use notation $\Re(a + bi + cj + dk) = a$ and $\Im(a + bi + cj + dk) = bi + cj + dk$ for the real and imaginary part of a quaternion respectively.)

These facts are so useful in any computation with quaternions that I expect you have seen them before.

Comment: It is *not* true that for "purely imaginary quaternions $u$ and $v$" that their imaginary parts anti-commute in general.  Rather, this is true iff $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular, when viewed as elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Consider, e.g. $u = i$ and $v = i + j$.

Comment: In this example $uv = -1 + k$ so that $\Im(uv) = k$ and $vu = -1 - k$ so that $\Im(vu) = -k$. Thus $\Im(vu) = -\Im(uv)$ as I wrote, what is the problem?

Comment: You are of course right that we do not have $uv = -vu$ unless $\Re(uv) = 0$, the latter condition being equivalent to being orthogonal in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I never claimed that $uv = -vu$ for purely imaginary quaternions in general!

Comment: Oh, I see that I misinterpreted what you wrote!  Thanks for the clarification.  I'd be happy to delete my original comment, since it no longer serves a purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The following answers the question only partially.

There are some general facts of Lie group theory that can be applied here. Let $G$ be a connected and compact Lie group. A maximal torus of $G$ is a maximal abelian, connected subgroup of $G$.

**Theorem.**
*Let $G$ be a connected and compact Lie group and $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$. Then $$G= \bigcup_{g\in G}gTg^{-1}$$*

Now if $G$ is a connected and compact Lie group, then a maximal torus $T$ is isomorphic to $(S^1)^{\times n} = \underbrace{S^1\times ...\times S^1}_{n\,times}$. Note that there exists a topological generator of $(S^1)^{\times n}$ i.e. there exists $t\in (S^1)^{\times n}$ such that $\{t^n\,|\,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $(S^1)^{\times n}$.

We prove now the following.

**Fact.** 
*Let $G$ be a connected and compact Lie Group and $A$ be an abelian subgroup of $G$ <s>contained in</s> containing a maximal torus $T$. Then $A=T$.*

**Proof.**
Closure of an abelian subgroup in $G$ is an abelian subgroup, so we may assume that $A$ is closed. Then $A$ is compact and $T\subseteq A$ is the connected component of the identity. Hence $T$ is open in $A$. These imply that $A/T$ is a finite abelian group. Next $T$ is a divisible abelian group. Thus $A = T\times B$, where $B$ is some finite group isomorphic with $A/T$. Suppose that there exists nontrivial $b\in B$ of order $m>0$. Let $t$ be a topological generator of $T$. Since $T$ is divisible group, there exists $t'\in T$ such that $t'^m = t$. Then $a = (t',b)\in A$ is a topological generator of $\langle T,b\rangle$. By **Theorem** there exists a maximal torus $T'$ of $G$ which contains $a$. Then $\langle T,b\rangle\subseteq T'$. Hence $T\subsetneq T'$ and this is contradiction with maximality of $T$. Therefore, $B$ is a trivial group and $A = T$.

Note that $S^3 = \mathbb{S}^0(\mathbb{H})$ is a compact, connected Lie group. All maximal tori are conjugate and cover $S^3$ by virtue of **Theorem** (it can also be viewed as an application of the existence of Hopf fibration as stated in M.Winter's comment). By **Fact** there are no abelian subgroups strictly containing a maximal torus of $S^3$. On the other hand $S^1$ is a maximal torus of $S^3$. This is precisely one of the copies of $U(1)$ indicated in the question.

Comment: It is absolutely true that all abelian subgroups of $SU(2)$ are subgroups of circle groups, and in that sense the question is a full answer and not just partial. However something is wrong in the proof. Obviously the 'fact' as stated is wrong: the finite groups from the original question are abelian but not circles.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Now I see what you mean

Comment: I am sorry. The statement of the fact was incorrect.

Comment: There is one last minor issue: 'By Fact there are no abelian subgroups containing a maximal torus of $S^3$' in the end of the post must be 'By Fact there are no abelian subgroups **strictly** containing a maximal torus of $S^3$.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for this fix.